# How to display a single object from response.data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Foloowing is my controller for displaying single book details from collection of json records

```
.controller('BookDetailsController', ['$scope','$http','$stateParams',function($scope,$http,$stateParams){
        $http({
            url: "/api/books/",
            method: "get",
            params: {id: $stateParams.id}
        }).then(function(response){
            $scope.books = response.data;
            console.log($scope.books);

        })
}]);
```

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Online Bookstore</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <img src="{{book.imgUrl}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <h2>{{book.title}}</h2>
            <p style="text-align:justify;">{{book.description}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How to display single book record from response.data; using above controller

Answer (score 1):

If `$scope.books` is an array, you can

## 1) Loop over the array to display all books

```
<div ng-repeat="b in books">
    {{b.title}}
    <img ng-src="{{b.imgUrl}}"
    ...
</div>
```

## 2) Display only one book from its position in the array

```
<h1>First book</h1>
{{books[0].title}}
<img ng-src="{{books[0].imgUrl}}"/>
```

Comment: it always displays same result if i follow above code... it should change dynamically on selecting particular book details it should display only that particular book full details

Comment: @Bikshus Ok, but which one? How are you *selecting* a book to display?

Comment: .state('bookdetails', {
        url:"/api/details/:id",
        controller: "BookDetailsController",
        templateUrl: "views/book-details.html"
    })
 <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="bookdetails({id: book._id})">View Details</a> By using this ui-sref

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `books` in the outer `<div>`:

```
....
<div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="book in books">
....
```

To display a single record (say for index `0`), simple use `books[0]` in the view:

```
  ..
  <img src="{{books[0].imgUrl}}" class="img-thumbnail" width="200" height="200">
</div>
<div class="col-md-9">
  <h2>{{books[0].title}}</h2>
  <p style="text-align:justify;">{{books[0].description}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: i want to display only one book details from array of objects

Answer (score 0):

Just take the first object inside the data,

```
$scope.book = response.data[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

if $scope.books is an array then you can use the ng-repeat as the above code by @mistails. it will simply create an list of books dynamically . and from the list you can select particular book and you can pass the id to fetch the book's whole data.

`<div ng-repeat="b in books" data-ng-click="showBookData(b)">
    {{b.title}}
    <img ng-src="{{b.imgUrl}}"
    ...
</div>`
showBookData()
 on the click you can open a modal and show the total details.